# C++ parsing a text file that is located online

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, parsing, text-files

Information about what I want to do:

-read in a few integer variables from a text file that will be located on a dropbox public folder.

-the variables will be used to trigger some if statements thus controlling my application remotely if I need to have it do something ( I would just save the variable I need to that text file and my program with would read from it every 5 seconds would see it and perform the required actions).

-this is a console application which is being built and compiled in visual studio 2010 on windows 7.  The software will also be running on a win7 computer.

I need help with:

- I already have read on using a library called libcurl.  The problem is that I do not know how to link this library with my project in vs2010.  Detailed instructions on how to do this on vs 2010 would be very helpful.

OR

- if you can think of a better and easier way to accomplish what I need done, offer some advice and direction

Comment: What did you try? Did you compile `libcurl` on your machine? How did you build it? How did you install it? Did you read http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/ ???

Comment: I compiled it and got the dll and lib but I just don't know how to link these so my project may use them.

Comment: So your question is how to link a `libcurl` that you just have built (I don't understand if you *installed* it). What did you try? How did you configure your compiler, when building your application, to ask it to link `libcurl` ???

Comment: I was trying to follow the instructions given by curl but they were for a much older vs so I think I did some steps wrong plus I could not find a lot of the settings or options they specified in the instructions.  All I did was compiled their vs project. Went to it's debug folder and grabbed the dll and lib file, I also have the folder with all the header files sitting on my c drive.  Now when I include curl in my project, it obviously can't find it because it is not linked.  What steps do I need to take for my project to see the dll lib and header files that I have sitting in a folder?

Comment: you should edit your question with what you have tried and why it did not work

Comment: Your question is tagged C++, so I will assume you are not doing a C only program. I would use Qt instead of lib curl. The API is easier and you don't have to build it yourself if you don't want to. Also, it will bring you other classes that you can take advantage of, besides networking.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're a novice, is that correct? If not then apologies for stating the obvious.

To use your compiled DLL in your application you need to 'add a reference' to it. You can do this by adding what is called a binary reference, where you simply tell visual studio where to find the dll. Or you can add a project reference if the project which is producing the dll is within the same solution. The best approach is to use something called nuget. It's a visual studio extension which automates the adding of binary references available from a public repository.

I have just done a search for libcurl on nuget.org and drew a blank. As I am unfamiliar with this library you may have better luck finding a nuget package as you will be a le to search using better terms that I did (curl and libcurl)

Whatever approach you take, just right-click on the project in which you want to use libcurl within the solution explorer and you should find an add reference option in the menu.